# Declaração de variáveis com chaves no Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, declaração-de-variável

Recentemente eu vi um tipo de código em Javascript, em alguns exemplos do Electron, que acredito ser parte do ES6. São declarações de variáveis no seguinte formato:

```
const electron = require('electron');
// Module to control application life.
const {app} = electron;
// Module to create native browser window.
const {BrowserWindow} = electron;
```

Aqui está sendo usado com `const`, mas não sei se isso também existe com `let` e `var`.

O importante aqui é que ao invés de declarar da forma usual

```
const app = electron;
const BrowserWindow = electron;
```

Estamos colocando `app` e `BrowserWindow` entre chaves.

O que significa esse tipo de declaração com o nome da variável dentro de chaves? Quando e como deve ser usado esse tipo de declaração?

Comment: O Sérgio já respondeu sua pergunta, mas caso você queira declarar essas chaves para pegar várias propriedades de um objeto seria melhor declarar o `with` em vez. Exemplo: `var obj = {prop: 5, ah: 2, uuh: true, y: false}; with(obj) { alert(prop); }`. O `with` expande um objeto e é suportado desde o ES1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso é uma tecnologia nova chamada [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) e que na prática é um atalho para declarar variáveis com o mesmo nome do que uma propriedade de um objeto, ou em arrays declarar indexando à posição de uma array.

Por exemplo:

```
var obj = {
  foo: 20,
  bar: 50
};

const {foo} = obj;

console.log(foo);
```

é um atalho de

```
const foo = obj.foo;
```

Isto é prático e pode ser usado em mais do que um de cada vez:

```
const {foo, bar} = obj;
```

que é  mesmo que

```
const foo = obj.foo;
const bar = obj.bar;
```

Isto também pode ser feito em arrays, neste caso importam-se as posições da array:

```
var arr = [0, 5, 10];
const [primeiro, segundo] = arr;

console.log(primeiro, segundo); // 0, 5
```

que é o mesmo que:

```
var primeiro = arr[0];
var segundo = arr[1];
```

Outra maneira bem útil é em argumentos de funções:

```js
var Ana = {
    nome: 'Ana',
    idade: 34
}

function info({nome,idade}) {
    console.log(`Pessoa: ${nome}, Idade: ${idade}`);
}

info(Ana); // Pessoa: Ana, Idade: 34
```

---

Notas:

- Exemplo: http://www.es6fiddle.net/iq15pxd4/
- esta tecnologia pode ser usada em `const`, `var`,`let`, `import` ou em argumentos de funções.