# Equivalente ao list() do PHP em Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Existe alguma função do Javascript equivalente ao `list()` do PHP?

Suponha este JSON:

```
{  
   "ALERTA":[  
      {  
         "TITULO":"Erro!",
         "MENSAGEM":"Seu nome parece estar incorreto"
      },
      {  
         "TITULO":"Erro!",
         "MENSAGEM":"Seu nome parece estar incorreto"
      }
   ]
}
```

Em PHP existe a possibilidade de usar o `list` junto ao `foreach`, *afim converter um índice, de uma array, para uma variável*.

```
foreach($json['ALERTA'] as list($titulo, $mensagem)){    
   // $titulo será "Erro!"
   // $mensagem será "Seu nome parece estar incorreto"
}
```

Isso faz com que não precise usar os índices `$variavel['TITULO']` e `$variavel[MENSAGEM]`, em seu lugar utilizo apenas `$titulo` e `$mensagem`.

Em Javascript/JQuery apenas conheço (e uso) deste método:

```
$.each(json['ALERTA'], function (nome, data) {
   // data['TITULO'] será "Erro!"
   // data['MENSAGEM'] será "Seu nome parece estar incorreto"
});
```

Porém queria ELIMINAR o uso de índices `['TITULO']` e `['MENSAGEM']`, apenas por *questões estéticas*.

**Desejo um resultado próximo a isto:**

```
$.each(json['ALERTA'], function (nome, list(titulo, mensagem)) {
   // titulo ser "Erro!"
   // mensagem ser "Seu nome parece estar incorreto"
});
```

Dessa forma, como no PHP, não iria usar o índice. Existe alguma função equivalente `list()` do PHP em Javascript, qual seria ela? Se não, existe outra solução para eliminar o uso de índices nesse caso (sem ser um novo loop)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há uma maneira de fazer isso usando JavaScript moderno (ES6). Falei sobre essa técnica *Destructuring assignment* aqui, [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137820/129). Também podes ler mais sobre isso na [MDN:Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Se combinares essa técnica com o (também novo) [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) podes atribuir os valores dessas propriedades *on the fly* assim:

```
for (let { TITULO, MENSAGEM } of json.ALERTA) {
    console.log(TITULO, MENSAGEM);
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://www.es6fiddle.net/irizeyxz/

Se precisas de suporte para Browsers antigos podes [converter isso com o Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/). Crias o código que precisas em ES6 e depois convertes. Neste caso o código do exemplo ficaria assim:

```js
"use strict";

var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
var _didIteratorError = false;
var _iteratorError = undefined;

try {
    for (var _iterator = json.ALERTA[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
        var _step$value = _step.value;
        var TITULO = _step$value.TITULO;
        var MENSAGEM = _step$value.MENSAGEM;

        console.log(TITULO, MENSAGEM);
    }
} catch (err) {
    _didIteratorError = true;
    _iteratorError = err;
} finally {
    try {
        if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
            _iterator.return();
        }
    } finally {
        if (_didIteratorError) {
            throw _iteratorError;
        }
    }
}
```

Para fazer isso com código à moda antiga podes fazer assim:

```
Array.prototype.lista = function() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var cb = args.pop();
    this.forEach(function(el) {
        var params = args.map(function(prop) {
            return el[prop];
        });
        cb.apply(this, params);
    });
}
```

e depois para usar:

```
json.ALERTA.lista('TITULO', 'MENSAGEM', function(tit, msg) {
    console.log(tit, msg);
});
```

### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7hxmzpd/